# How to make a new line on a form using asp.net mvc in a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling to make a new line, i have checkbox each must have its own new line. Any idea how to achieve this using bootstrap class within a form-group row?

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Dietary requirement" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dietary requirements</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.None)<label for="None">None</label>
        <hr />
    </div>
                                
    <div class="form-group row">
        &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Vegetarian)<label for="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change css class `col-sm-2` to `col-sm-12`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `col-sm-2` to `col-sm-12` and remove all `&nbsp;` then add `new { @class="col-md-12" }` *htmlAttributes* to `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Vegetarian)`

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Dietary requirement" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Dietary requirements</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.None)<label for="None">None</label>
        <hr />
    </div>
                            
    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DietMain.Vegetarian, new { @class="col-md-12" }) 
        <label for="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</label>
    </div>
</div>
```